# Include <script> element in Ionic 2 html file

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, gulp, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic 2 development and web dev, coming from iOS applications in Swift.
Right now I'm trying to follow a tutorial for web to build a simple maps application that includes a static Google map element in a blank Ionic 2 project page. When I run `ionic serve --lab` the nav-bar loads properly with the page title but otherwise the screen is blank, and console generates no errors.

As I understand it, including the following two `<script>` elements (API key redacted) in an HTML file to build for a website should generate a map at the specified coordinates, but it does not work in an Ionic 2 project:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="API_KEY"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      var center = new google.maps.LatLng(46.878, -113.9966);
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: center;
        zoom: 13
      });
    }
  // This listens for the map to load...
  // Ionic native page load listener = onPageLoaded(), so if this doesn't work you can try that
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the actual google.maps script from the google cdn?

Comment: @misha130 I guess not, I was following an old tutorial (https://ionicallyspeaking.com/2016/06/07/google-places-autocomplete-and-ionic-2/comment-page-1/#comment-209). Do you know where I can find that?

Comment: A good tutorial http://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/ slightly outdated cause rc0